# trouble installing RVM on a mac

Tags: macos, rvm

I am trying to set up a local Rails environment, and I am having issues with getting RVM installed.

Here is the error I get:

```
$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    136      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>

The contents of my /usr/local folder are as follows:
bin          man
etc          mysql
hermes       mysql-5.1.56-osx10.5-x86_64
include      rvm
info         share
lib
```

I have some working knowledge of what's going on here, but help on what I'm missing or whether I'm approaching this the wrong way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Use the new RVM installer for either user and/or root installs instead, it defaults to `head`.

```
user$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Alternatively you can install the stable release like this:

```
user$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

RTFM material is located at https://rvm.io/rvm/install and https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Comment: What is the difference between this and the info at rvm.io?

Answer (score 7):

On my Mac OS X 10.5.8 I had to use

bash < <(curl -Lks https://rvm.io/install/rvm) or it failed silently.

The -s switch by itself absolutely does not work.  Fails silently.

It's annoying when people answer with the generic info anyone can find at the RVM site.  Please try to actually answer this when you've actually succeeded in installing ON A MAC.

Matt if my fix does not work for you then would you let us know? Thanks.

Comment: Wayne thanks for the note below. This worked for my mac: rvm implode, then bash < <(curl -Lks https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm), then rvm package install readline (to get around the faulty one I have elsewhere in the system), then rvm remove 1.8.7, then finally rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr

Comment: Wow. nogrub. I signed up just to tell you how much you saved me with your fix. I couldn't find this approached documented anywhere else on the web- it worked for me!

Comment: glad to help. rvm is totally worth the effort!

Comment: "It's annoying when people answer with the generic info anyone can find at the RVM site. Please try to actually answer this when you've actually succeeded in installing ON A MAC."

This is amusing as RVM is developed mainly 'ON A MAC' :)

Comment: This will no longer work. Please stick to using my answer here and the RVM documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On mac 10.5 I had to run this command
   $ echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
followed by this
   $  bash -s stable < <(curl -Lks --insecure https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
I hope this is helpful to someone out there.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `-s` option to curl.

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```